# What is the name of the resetting ratchet component found most often in head rests?

Tags: furniture

There is a component which I've seen most often in car seat headrests which acts as a ratchet.  You can pull the headrest forward and it will lock at steps until you pull it too far, and it will reset all the way back.

It's sort of a ratchet mechanism which resets after a certain range of motion.

I don't know what it's called.  I've tried "resetting ratchet", "resetting step lock", and many other queries.

Do you know the name of this component?

Comment: in crimping pliers it's called controlled cycle,  in furniture I don't know,

Comment: I know the device you're talking about, and it's used in many places in autos, but I'm not so sure about its use in furniture or other home applications. You may be better off asking at [mechanics.se].

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be about home improvement.

Comment: Why close the question?  What do you even get out of that?

Answer (score 1):

I've found them called "Headrest Hinge" on Amazon and Ebay.

https://www.amazon.com/s?k=headrest+hinge

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer. It would be _most_ helpful if you would also click the check-mark so that others know that this has been resolved, especially if they should be looking for a similar item.

Answer (score -1):

Mine just stop at the limit and the simple position control is a spring loaded ball and detent.

Comment: This is a different component than what I'm looking for, but it could be used by others in similar circumstances.